# Why is node version not changing in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, nvm

I am trying t update my  Node version globally. I have Node v17.8.0  in my local machine, but when I check the node version that I am in VS code; it is still using v14.9.0.

I have tried to re-start, but it is still not changing. What should I do to update the node version to the latest version in VS code? I am a mac user.

Comment: How did you install/update Node.js. What do you mean with _"the Node.js verions in VS code"_? How do you use Node.js in VS Code? How is this realted to XCode?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to solve this problem by setting a new default version of nodejs via nvm:

```
nvm alias default 18
```

After that when I restart VS Code it starts using node v18.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Node v17.8.0 (which is different from having it just downloaded).
Run: `node -v` it should output something like `v17.8.0`. If not, then you need to configure your computer to use the new version (I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your node versions.

It is also possible that you defined `runtimeVersion: 14.9.0` at your [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration). You might want to 1) remove that, or 2) set it to 17.8.0.

Comment: Somehow I guess NVM is the problem. It's already tagged in the question. AFAIK NVM requires settings in .bashrc or .zshrc, but many tools don't evaluate these scripts. It's simpler with [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n).